# create session for user login VB.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

some variables in my class:

1-companyID

2-CompanyName(UserName)

3-CompanyPwd(password)

4- CompanyLogo

5-Email.

i wana create session content all of these fields to use some of them in ctrls.

Answer (score 2):

Store the class object in session

```
public class Company
{
  public int Id { set;get;}
  public string Name { set;get;}
  public string Logo { set;get;}  
}
```

To store it in session

```
Company objCompany=new Company();
objCompany.ID=34;
objCompany.Name="Chase";
objCompany.Logo="chase_logo.PNG";

Session["company"]=objCompany;
```

To Retrieve from Session,

```
Company objComp=null;
if(Session["company"]!=null)
{
  objComp=(Company) Session["company"];
}
```

Ideally I would wrap this in a method like this

```
public Company GetCurrentCompany()
{
    Company objComp=null;
    if(Session["company"]!=null)
    {
      objComp=(Company) Session["company"];
    }
}
```

so that i can simply call `GetCurrentCompany` method  if i want the stored company in different places.

Comment: alright now how can i use session in other place as ctrl ?? and how can i retrieve one field from session?

Comment: @Alaahafethburghall ctrl means ?

Comment: Control i meant any page how to call the session, because ive used the session depends on function called Find to find everything in the class so how can i call one value as "CompanyName" in control page

Comment: @Alaahafethburghall: Session will be available in all the pages as long as the user session exist. So you can use the way i mentioned in the answer (**To Retrieve from Session part**)